# How to automatically create XSDs from request, response

Tags: java, rest

I have sample requests and responses for a RESTful service. How to create XSD from them? Is there an automated way or I should manually do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that what you are actually asking for is creating and XSD out of example XML files.

If so using trang (http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) is one of the options available:

```
java -jar trang.jar Sample.xml Sample.xsd
```